# best way to add classpath to ant task in gradle

Tags: java, ant, groovy, gradle

I'm attempting to pre-generate jpa 2 metamodel classes using a custom gradle task that uses the antbuilder.

so far my code looks like this:

```
task generateJpaMetaModel {
    doFirst {
        sourceSets.generated.output.classesDir.mkdirs()
        ant.javac (
                srcDir: "$projectDir/src/main/java",
                destDir: sourceSets.generated.output.classesDir,
                failonerror: true,
                fork: true
        ) {
            classpath {
                pathElement(location: buildscript.configurations.classpath.asPath)
                pathElement(location: configurations.compile.asPath)
            }
            compilerarg (value: "-proc:only")
        }
    }
    inputs.files "$projectDir/src/main/java"
    outputs.files sourceSets.generated.output.classesDir
}
compileGeneratedJava.dependsOn generateJpaMetaModel
```

I have a custom `generated` sourceSet added to my project which applies the Java Plugin.

in my dependencies I have various JPA libraries:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    provided "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$libraryVersions.servlet_api"
    provided "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:$libraryVersions.hibernate_jpa_2"
}
```

And in my buildscript i have a dependency on the metamodel generation jars:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:$libraryVersions.hibernate_jpamodelgen"
    }
}
```

Running the generateJpaMetaModel task gives me the following output even though i thought i added the class path correctly:

```
[ant:javac] C:\Users\me\IdeaProjects\myproject\subprojects\core\src\main\java\com\example\myproject\core\model\User.java:152: error: cannot find symbol
[ant:javac]     @Column(name = ONE_COLUMN)
[ant:javac]      ^
[ant:javac]   symbol:   class Column
[ant:javac]   location: class User
[ant:javac] C:\Users\me\IdeaProjects\myproject\subprojects\core\src\main\java\com\example\myproject\core\model\User.java:155: error: cannot find symbol
[ant:javac]     @Column(name = TWO_COLUMN)
[ant:javac]      ^
[ant:javac]   symbol:   class Column
[ant:javac]   location: class User
[ant:javac] C:\Users\me\IdeaProjects\myproject\subprojects\core\src\main\java\com\example\myproject\core\model\User.java:158: error: cannot find symbol
[ant:javac]     @Column(name = RED_COLUMN)
[ant:javac]      ^
[ant:javac]   symbol:   class Column
[ant:javac]   location: class User
[ant:javac] C:\Users\me\IdeaProjects\myproject\subprojects\core\src\main\java\com\example\myproject\core\model\User.java:161: error: cannot find symbol
[ant:javac]     @Column(name = BLUE_COLUMN)
[ant:javac]      ^
[ant:javac]   symbol:
----- End of the daemon log -----
```

After reading some forums i decided to try add the classpath with addToAntBuilder method on FileCollection class:

```
(configurations.compile +  buildscript.configurations.classpath)
    .addToAntBuilder(ant, 'fileset', FileCollection.AntType.FileSet)
ant.javac (
        srcDir: "$projectDir/src/main/java",
        destDir: sourceSets.generated.output.classesDir,
        failonerror: true,
        fork: true,
        classpath: 'fileset'
) {
    compilerarg (value: "-proc:only")
}
```

However it still gives me the same output.

Can someone point out what the best way is to add a classpath to an ant task?

**UPDATE:**

here is my third attempt with the same output:

```
sourceSets.generated.output.classesDir.mkdirs()
ant.javac (
        srcDir: "$projectDir/src/main/java",
        destDir: sourceSets.generated.output.classesDir,
        failonerror: true,
        includeantruntime: true
) {
    (configurations.compile +  buildscript.configurations.classpath)
        .addToAntBuilder(ant, 'classpath', FileCollection.AntType.ResourceCollection)
    compilerarg (value: "-proc:only")
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is my fourth failing attempt using peter's suggestion:

```
task generateJpaMetaModel(type: JavaCompile) {
    source = fileTree("$projectDir/src/main/java")
    destinationDir = sourceSets.generated.output.classesDir
    sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
    targetCompatibility = "1.7"
    classpath = configurations.compile + buildscript.configurations.classpath
    options.compilerArgs = ["-proc:only"]    
}
```

I still have the same output

Comment: Why don't you do the generation with a `JavaCompile` task? You might not even need a separate `JavaCompile` task for this.

Comment: I tried this with the JavaCompile task and it does the same thing still. See question update 2

Comment: `hibernate-jpamodelgen` shouldn't be declared as a `buildscript` dependency, as it isn't used in the build script. Anyway, chances are that the class path passed to `generateJpaMetaModel` just doesn't contain the dependency which declares the `@Column` annotation type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the `compile` configuration did not contain the dependencies from the provided configuration. When I think about it, This makes sense as i do not want the provided jars ending up in my subproject jar/war if they will be provided by the container at runtime.

My providedConfiguration.gradle plugin file contains the following:

```
/**
 * Adds a configuration named 'provided'. 'Provided' dependencies
 * are incoming compile dependencies that aren't outgoing
 * dependencies. In other words, they have no effect on transitive
 * dependency management.
 */

configurations {
    provided.extendsFrom(compile)
    testCompile.extendsFrom(provided)
}

sourceSets.main {
    compileClasspath += configurations.provided
}

plugins.withType(IdeaPlugin) {
    idea.module.scopes.PROVIDED.plus += configurations.provided
}
```

So instead of adding the compile configuration to the classpath of the JavaCompile task, I should add the provided configuration instead:

```
task generateJpaMetaModel(type: JavaCompile) {
    ...
    classpath = configurations.provided + buildscript.configurations.classpath
    ...    
}
```

Comment: `buildscript.configurations.classpath` has a different purpose, and shouldn't be involved here.